# sending JSON to server windows phone 8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webclient

i'm trying to send JSON string to server using Web Client Class but No result is returned,i've tried Rest Client plugin to make sure that server is returning something, here's my postRequest method `

```
 public static void PostRequest(WebClient webclient,string data,string
 url,string header,string method)
             {
                 Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
                 webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = header;
                 webclient.UploadStringAsync(uri,method,data);  
           }
```

and here is where i invoke this method

```
 string newUserJson="{"User_Name":"yosyos","First_Name":"gfhgas","Last_Name":"jagfshg"}";

              wc = new WebClient();
              wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wb_UploadStringCompleted);
             string url = "http://670b9ada.ngrok.com/laravelProjects/TestVisWall/public/users";
              helper.PostRequest( wc, newUserJson, url, "application/json", "POST");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `WebClient`, it's discouraged from Microsoft. 
Try RestSharp library, in my opinion is a very good one. Add recerense to Restsharp, Nuget method is faster: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("baseurl");    
var request = new RestRequest("/path/script.php", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "json string", ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                                         {
                                             if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                             {
                                                //OK
                                             }
                                         });
    }
```

Comment: i'm trying it now but i want to know the difference between the url given on the RestClient Constructor "baseurl" and the url given in the RestRequest Constructor "/path/script.php" ?

Comment: It depends on your scenario, if you are performing a single request, you can pass full url to the constrctor. Personally, I perform many request to the same rest service so the base url is static and the only changing thing is the remote file I'm sending data to.

Comment: thanks,
but i've tried it and it's the same as the Web client .. no respond is sent

Comment: Do you mean the response? The code is correct, so the problem might be the server you are trying to reach.